# Properly storing an object in chrome.storage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object, google-chrome-extension, associative-array

I'm trying to store an object in my chrome extension containing other objects using chrome.storage - but am having trouble initializing it and properly fetching it using chrome.storage.sync.get. I understand that I'm supposed to get objects in the form of `chrome.storage.sync.get(key: "value", function(obj) {}` - the issue is I'm not sure how to

- Initialize the object the first time with get
- Properly update my object with set

I have the following code to create the object and add the data I need.

```
allData = {};
currentData = {some: "data", goes: "here"};
allData[Object.keys(allData).length] = currentData;
```

This will correctly give me an object with it's first key (0) set to currentData. `(Object: {0: {some: "data", goes: "here"}})` Working as intended, and `allData[Object.keys(allData).length] = currentData;` will properly push whatever currentData is at the time into my Object later on.

But how do I properly store this permanently in chrome.storage? `chrome.storage.sync.get("allData", function(datas) {})` fails to create an empty allData variable, as does `allData: {}`, `allData = {}`, and a variety of different things that return either `undefined` or another error. How do I properly initialize an empty object and store it in chrome.storage? Or am I going about this all wrong and need to break it down into associative arrays in order for it to work?

I essentially need that small block of working code above to be stored permanently with chrome.storage so I can work with it as needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need to set the data inside the storage:

```
allData = {};
currentData = {some: "data", goes: "here"};

// to initialize the all data using the storage
chrome.storage.sync.get('allData', function(data) {
  // check if data exists.
  if (data) {
      allData = data;
  } else {
      allData[Object.keys(allData).length] = currentData;
  }
});

// Save it using the Chrome extension storage API.
chrome.storage.sync.set({'allData': allData}, function() {
  // Notify that we saved.
  message('Settings saved');
});
```

After that you should be able to access the data using the `chrome.storage.sync.get('allData', function(){ ... })` interface.

Comment: How do I initialize it at first? _ie: If it's not in storage, set allData to currentData. Otherwise, set allData from storage before appending currentData._

Comment: Take a look on the code above, I updated it with the get code to initialize the data.

Comment: THIS CODE IS WRONG. `chrome.storage.get` is asynchronous, meaning that it returns immediately, before the callback is called. This allows the `chrome.storage.set` call below it to run immediately after, using the value for `allData` as it was initialized (in this case an empty object). To ensure you `set` only after you `get` the data (so that `allData` actually holds the retrieved data),  you must put the `set` call inside the `get` callback.

Comment: In addition to what @zr0gravity7 pointed out, this answer is also wrong with regards to MV3 which uses service workers which are short-lived and re-executed a lot (so global variables will get reset). Of course this wasn't the case at the time this answer was written, but just saying for awareness of future readers.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do this with the new JavaScript (ECMAScript 6), have a look into [Enhanced Object Properties](http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand):

```
var currentData = {some: "data", goes: "here"};
chrome.storage.local.set({allData: currentData });
```

In the old way, was something like this:

```
var obj = {};
var key = "auth";
obj[key] += "auth";
obj[key] = JSON.stringify({someKey: someValue});
```

Comment: This really neither answers the question nor even uses the Enhanced Object Properties that are linked.